# In IEx why \t becomes spaces but not tab?

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

In IEx, puts `\t` prints up to 7 spaces.

```
iex(1)> IO.puts "1\t2"
1       2  # same as 1\s\s\s\s\s\s\s2
```

However if I put the same code in a file, and run it in bash, it gives me the real tab

```
$ elixir test.exs
1   2      # same as 1\t2
```

You can use Textmate and turn on invisible character to see the difference.

My questions are:

1. Why it behaves like this way?
2. Is there a way to make `\t` into a real tab in IEx?

Note: this is on Mac OSX.

Comment: Is there a setting like "Turn tabs into spaces" in the software somewhere?

Comment: I get the same results here, definitely seems strange. However, iex ist just for debugging purposes, you should not use it to generate output, then to copy and paste it somewhere. A safer way would be writing directly to a file or redirecting output to a file with `elixir text.exs > outfile.txt`.

Comment: Are you 100% sure it isn't Textmate's fault? I've run your example in iex 7.2.1 (Windows/cygwin) and pasted the output to `cat -t -v -e`, and it definitely prints a Tab character.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt note the question is about iex, not elixir. Elixir of course prints a tab, but iex seems to convert tabs to spaces.

Comment: @PatrickOscity I've checked with iex, not elixir. And iex in Cygwin definitely prints a Tab (not only in Cygwin, but from the Windows command prompt, as well). So it might be OS dependent.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt if I pipe to cat or redirect to a file I get the tab as well, but printing to tty seems to produce spaces, i.e. when I just run iex directly and then copy & paste. Can you confirm this?

Comment: @PatrickOscity when running concurrent code is more convenient to run in IEx to generate output. Otherwise it needs to provide --no-halt option for elixir command to show up the output generated in other processes.